# .htaccess Only for www. Subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How do I construct my .htaccess file so that it adds www to the beginning of the address mysite.com, but doesn't add www. to the beginning of other subdomains such as test.mysite.com? My .htaccess file currently looks like this:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com
```

Instead of

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
```

Comment: It would be that simple if it wasn't for the usage of ttp://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1, because that seems to mean the domain can be variable...

Comment: Althought i might be wrong and then your answer is DEFINITELY the simplest and most obvious choice

Comment: The lack of configurability _could_ be overcome by setting a proper `SERVER_NAME`, in which case the line would most likely be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^%{SERVER_NAME}`

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer; the domain name is not variable. Can you please explain how your solution would work now?

Comment: In it's current state, it just checks whether the domain start with `mysite.com`, and only then follows the RewriteRule. If there is a small chance you'll have a  `mysite.com.mysite.com` subdomain, anchor it on both ends (`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$`), so the rule to redirect to www. only goes in affect if the hostname is _exactly_ "mysite.com". On a side note: I doubt you own `mysite.com`, `example.com` is reserved for this kind of thing ;)

Comment: User said that domain was not variable, you win @Wrikken ;)

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin: Phew, luckily, good game, on to the next ;)

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thank you all so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I just don't know the darn rule to get only the characters for domain naming so i'll try this but it might fail on some subjects:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(\.[a-z]{2,4})+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This will force all domains that START with one word and a TLD to be forwarded to www.samedomain.tld but subdomains wont be hit...

Comment: My solution allows you to run this code on a multi domain site but has some limitations. Such as main domains with 4 characters or less (ex: sex.com will still be hit on my.sex.com because my will fit the first rule and .sex.com will hit the repeat rule at the end)

Comment: `.museum` is the longest current tld I know, and there are a lot of countries using doubles, like `.co.uk`...

Comment: The doubles are handled by the (...)+ at the end, but the museum, thats a new one. In that case, we can't really use my solution...

Comment: That, and the fact `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+` matches `www` ;)  I think lookbehinds weren't possible in RewriteRules, but those  may overcome that, I'll check.

Comment: On a note, no, lookahead & family can unfortunately not be used here (POSIX regexes as opposed to PCRE ones in mod_rewrite).